URL.checkResourceIsReachable() throws error if file is on FTP server and name contains special characters
I have a file named ä.txt (with German umlaut) on my FTP server. I select it like this:
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.runModal()
let source = openPanel.urls[0]

Running this code unexpectedly throws an error:
do {
    print(try source.checkResourceIsReachable())
} catch {
    print(error) // Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory”
}

Manipulating the URL also seems to change the underlying characters:
print(source)                            // file:///Volumes/abc.com/httpdocs/%C3%A4.txt
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: source.path)) // file:///Volumes/abc.com/httpdocs/a%CC%88.txt

Note that both variants of the URL above also throw the same error when running URL.checkResourceIsReachable().
If I download the file to my Mac, then both variants print file:///Users/me/Downloads/a%CC%88.txt and neither of them throws an error when running URL.checkResourceIsReachable().
After a few more tests, I noticed that, while try source.checkResourceIsReachable() throws an error and FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: source.path) returns false, calling open(source.path, O_RDONLY) returns a valid file descriptor if source is a directory; if it's a regular file, it returns -1.
What is the problem? How can I correctly access this file on the FTP server?
